# Python Linux IBM Lotus Notes 9 - export DB

Tags: python, database, lotus

I have been struggling with this for days - I would like to do script via Python which will automatically download  some information or whole file/s from DB. Only what can I do is manually export file as txt format. Maybe Java will be better than Python to do dat but still how to connect to database?

For example
a) DB in Lotus:

```
Server: LOLXXXDB001/IBMXXXXX
Server address: lolXXXdb01.ibm.com
filename: Reference/xxx.nsf
Link: Notes://:LOLXXXDB01/QWERTY/12345
```

b) login to Lotus:

```
certificate file: /home/usr/XXXX000A.ID
login: John Doe/USA/IBM
pass: XxXxXx
```

Python's module:

```
import ibm_db
ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;
                PWD=password;", "", "")
```

How to setup/match DB in lotus with IBM_DB module?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was trying just connect to IBM/Lotus Notes's DB via python with this information like server address/filename etc. but I dont know how exactly to do that (ibm_db module for example) so I stuck at the start of my adventure :X

Comment: @NicoHaase Did you make it?

Comment: What should I have done? You haven't shared any attempt for anybody else to reproduce the problem, and I don't have such a database server at hand to fiddle around with it

Comment: The only way you can connect to Domino is either through the client (Java/Com) , Corba (java), ODBC if you have the connector, Domino Access Service if enabled, or any other custom webservice you create on the server. The the Python IBM_DB module is only for DB2, which is a completly different database.